# How to turn tabs into blockquotes using perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

If I have HTML that are lines like the following: (`\t` means Tab character)

```
<P>\tSome text</P>
<P>\t\tSome text</P>
<P>\tSome text</P>
```

Using regex, how can I convert the above to:

```
<P><BLOCKQUOTE>Some text</BLOCKQUOTE></P>
<P><BLOCKQUOTE><BLOCKQUOTE>Some text</BLOCKQUOTE></BLOCKQUOTE></P>
<p><BLOCKQUOTE>Some text></BLOCKQUOTE></P>
```

At the moment I have:

```
for $line (@lines)
{
   $line =~ s{^(<P>(?:<BLOCKQUOTE>)*)\t(.+?)((?:</BLOCKQUOTE>)*</P>)$}{$1<BLOCKQUOTE>$2</BLOCKQUOTE>$3}g;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you trying to match a tab like the whitespace, or the literal characters `\\ ` and `t` ?

Comment: @NickReed I am trying to match actual tab characters, not the literal `\t`

Comment: Alright, and what language are you using to replace the characters - is that JQuery?

Comment: @NickReed The language is perl, using regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (@lines)
{
   s{^<P>(\t+)(.+?)</P>$}{<P> . "<BLOCKQUOTE>" x length($1) . $2 . "</BLOCKQUOTE>" x length($1) . "</P>"}gie;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The tricky bit here is to somehow enter as many replacement tags as there are tabs.

I'd go with multiple passes, first counting the tabs and then going over the string again to replace them with the right number of open-close replacement tags (`BLOCKQUOTE`). In this case a single regex is bound to be *much* more complex and thus that much harder to tweak and maintain.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my @test_strings = ( 
    qq(<p>\t\ttwo tabs</p>),
    qq(<p>\tone tab</p>),
    qq(<p>no tab</p>),
    qq(<div>\tnot paragraph</div>),
);

say for @test_strings;  say '';

for (@test_strings) 
{
    if (my ($tabs) = /<p>(\t+)/)          # capture consecutive tabs
    { 
        my $nt = () = $tabs =~ /\t/g;     # count them

        my $ot = "<BLOCKQUOTE>"  x $nt;   # open-tag
        my $ct = "</BLOCKQUOTE>" x $nt;   # close-tag

        s{<p> \t+ ([^\t].+?) </p>}{<p>$ot$1$ct</p>}x; 

        say;
    }       
}
```

Prints

```
<p>             two tabs</p>
<p>     one tab</p>
<p>no tab</p>
<div>   not paragraph</div>

<p><BLOCKQUOTE><BLOCKQUOTE>two tabs</BLOCKQUOTE></BLOCKQUOTE></p>
<p><BLOCKQUOTE>one tab</BLOCKQUOTE></p>
<p>no tab</p>
<div>   not paragraph</div>
```

Notes

- As it stands this works with at most one paragraph (`<p>...</p>`) in the string, while

  ```
  while (my ($tabs) = /<p>(\t+)/g) { ... }
  ```

  (instead of `if (...)`) appears to work with multiple paragraphs. Needs more testing
- Counting itself uses [`=()=` "operator"](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perlsecret/lib/perlsecret.pod#Goatse). It imposes list context on its right-hand side, so the regex returns the list of matches, assigned to a scalar on its left. Thus we get the count.

  In this case, with `$tabs` consisting of only the tab characters, one can simply do

  ```
   my $nt = split '', $tabs;
  ```

  (Update: really just `my $nt = length $tabs;`, as in other answers)

  I still use the regex since it'll work for a string with things other than just tabs, as well
- The code replaces only the consecutive tabs in the beginning, right after `<p>`, not any that may come later in the string (how I see the requirement).

  This is provided for by following the tabs in the pattern (`\t+`) with a *single* non-tab character and then any characters, `[^\t].*?`. Thus this matches for a string with more tabs further down but replaces only the leading "block" of tabs

Comment: Your answer is how I approached it first, but I wanted to do it a one line regex.  See my answer which uses the `\G`anchor.

Comment: Sorry, my answer didn't actually work.  See my updated answer.

Comment: To the reader: I have no idea for the -1, and I looked and looked.  A job like this can of course depend on details a lot but the code here works for the question as asked, as far as I can see

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, with some expression similar to:

```
(?i)<p>\s{2,}(.*?)<\/p>
```

and replace with

```
<p><BLOCKQUOTE>$1</BLOCKQUOTE></p>
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/gGm8Tb/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/gGm8Tb/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Answer (score 2):

I was going to say regex isn't powerful enough to do this on its own, but it looks like Perl can more than do the job! This logic should be fairly painless to extend for multiple lines of input.

```perl
#your input text
$string = "<P>      Some text</P>";

#get the number of tab characters present in the string - note that this assumes they're all at the start
my @matches = $string =~ /\t/g;

#get the other parts of the string
$string =~ /(<P>)(\t+)(.*)(<\/P>)/g;

#add <BLOCKQUOTE> once for each match at the locations you've specified, and also cut out the existing tabs
$out = $1 . "<BLOCKQUOTE>" x @matches . $3 . "<BLOCKQUOTE>" x @matches . $4;
print "$out"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [Mojo::DOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM), so we aren't restricted by organization of whitespace or edge cases:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Mojo::DOM;

my $html = <<"HTML";
<P>\tSome text</P>
<P>\t\tSome text</P>
<P>\tSome text</P>
HTML

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new($html);
foreach my $p ($dom->find('p')->each) {
  my $content = $p->content;
  $content =~ s/^(\t*)//;
  my $count = length $1;
  $p->content($content);
  $p->wrap_content('<blockquote></blockquote>') for 1..$count;
}

print $dom->to_string;
```

Result:

```
<p><blockquote>Some text</blockquote></p>
<p><blockquote><blockquote>Some text</blockquote></blockquote></p>
<p><blockquote>Some text</blockquote></p>
```

(You can use [XML mode](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM#CASE-SENSITIVITY) if you really want to keep it case sensitive.)